# An explicit projection formula of the Littlewood-Richardson rule

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

According to Fulton & Harris's *Representation theory*, given a vector space $V$ and $d\in \mathbb N$, one gets a factorization of $V^{\otimes d}$ by $\oplus_\lambda V^\lambda$, where $\lambda$ runs over all Young diagrams of $d$ with less than $\dim V$ rows, and each $V^\lambda$ is an irreducible representation of $GL(V)$. The Littlewood-Richardson's rule computes the multiplicity of $V^\mu$ in the tensor product $V^\lambda\otimes V^\tau$, saying that $V^\mu$ appears in $V^\lambda\otimes V^\tau$ $N_{\lambda\tau\mu}$ times, where $N_{\lambda\tau\mu}$ is the number of *strict $\tau$-extensions of $\lambda$ to $\mu$*.

In particular, if $N_{\lambda\tau\mu}=1$, there is a canonical projection $V^\lambda\otimes V^\tau\to V^\mu$. I am wondering that is it possible in general (or in some specific cases) we can write an explicit formula for this map? In other words, I want a construction of this map other than just its existence.

Even in easy cases, when $d$ and $\dim V$ are small, I don't know how to proceed. My current knowledge is that the projection is not the obvious one, namely embeding both $V^\lambda\otimes V^\tau$ and $V^\mu$ into $V^{\otimes(d+d')}$ and viewing the later as a subspace of the former. The inclusion map is more complex than "acting as identity on the source". Could someone give me a hint or point out some references? Thank you so much.